# Overleaf adding of .tex file

Tags: overleaf

I am unable to add a .tex file to my project when selecting Add Files .. Blank File. It complains that it does not have the right extension, even though I add the .tex suffice to the new file. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Looks like you have to close that error message manually by clicking on it. So if you by accident hit enter before completing the filename with `.tex`, and then added the extension, the file will be created, but you still need to close the error.

Comment: Check also that your operating system may have hidden the _real_ extension from view on your computer, e.g. `file.something` shows as `file`. Then when you thought you've renamed it to `file.tex`, it's actually really `file.tex.something`!

Comment: Thanks !,  I now see that I do not get that error anymore. And that it recognizes the file now !

Comment: @LianTzeLim Do you think any reasonable thing can be done here? With the given information, i don t think the question can be answered.

Comment: sorry @Johannes_B , I don't think there was enough info to say what was exactly the problem.

Comment: @LianTzeLim I think the first time the OP simply forgot to "click to close" on the error window and it doesn't go away...